# Is there an equivalent of QSpace, but vertical?

Tags: quasar-framework

I have a page that consists of

- a container: `<q-layout class='q-pa-md full-height flex column'>`
- inside this container are three `<div>`.

I would like the first and third `<div>` to take the space of its contents (this is done by default), and the second `<div>` is intended to be empty and take all remaining space (pushing the top and bottom `<div>` away).

That would be the equivalent of a `<q-space>`, but for vertical space.

Since I dod not find anything relevant in the [documentation for columns](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/column), I tried to make it a `<div style="flex: 1"></div>` but it did not expand as expected.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the middle of two elements to be empty as you've described, you can give `justify-between` to the container.

Based on [an example from the docs](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/column#example--vertical-alignment):

```css
.column > div {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}

.column {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<!--
  Forked from:
  https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/column#example--vertical-alignment
-->
<div id="q-app" style="height: 200px;">
  <div class="full-height column justify-between">
    <div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.8.4/dist/quasar.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.8.4/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to have some content in the middle which takes all the space it can get, then you would give `col` class to it.